# Which path to take after learning Java standard edition?

Tags: java

I learned java standard edition and looking forward to learn through. My first thought was to learn android or google web toolkit. But still got no idea what to do? How to choose the path?

Thanks!

Comment: Pick a project and start implementing. When you get stuck ask questions here after some research.

Comment: There is no single right answer to this question that is asking for opinions and is typically an invitation for a discussion. SO is not really appropriate for such questions. You should maybe consider rephrasing it a bit to make it more SO compliant.

Answer (score 10):

Try building something instead of learning. It doesn't really matter how many books you've read, what really counts is the stuff you created.

Answer (score 4):

Java is only a tool, something that is supposed to help you develop whatever you need. What you should ask yourself is "what do I want to do" and then find (or simply ask here) the technologies/frameworks/whatever that will help you achieve your goals. Then come up with a project and start coding+reading.

"How to chose the path" unfortunately it's something YOU have to figure out YOURSELF, no one should tell you what you should/want to do (don't worry I'm also having the same problem currently).

Answer (score 3):

Java EE 6.  Gives you a lot of Java experience (if you do a real application) which is nice, plus you will use it for any non-trivial Java web application.

Answer (score 2):

Android might be good.  We'll see how long it lasts in the face of Oracle's patent infringement lawsuits.  Google has money and lawyers, too.

You can go for Java EE 6 and the EJB 3.1 spec.

You could choose the "no EJB" path and go with [Spring](http://www.springframework.org).

You could learn graphics with Java 2D, Java 3D, and OpenGL.

You could go for scientific computing and Apache Commons Math.

There are a million paths.  Pick a good one.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much you know about programming. If you are a beginner in programming too, then design patterns is a good choice to learn!

Answer (score 0):

Start involving in an open source project, e.g. [eclipse](http://eclipse.org).